# What is Different Between AjaxContext and ContextSwitch

Tags: zend-framework

What is Different Between AjaxContext and ContextSwitch ?
What If i didnt use AjaxContext in my Async Ajax controller?

Answer (score 4):

AjaxContext is a type of ContextSwitch, which switches context based on the presence of the  the XMLHttpRequest header. ContextSwitch is a more generic way of switching contexts based on the presence of a format variable in the URL. E.g. you could set your routing up so that appending '.json' onto the request will get your controller to return a JSON response.

Comment: What If i didnt use AjaxContext in my Async Ajax controller?

Comment: If you don't do any form of context switching for ajax requests, they will return a full HTML page, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: even when i put $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
in my init() function

Comment: Well sure, but the context switch helper does this for you. You don't have to use it though.

Comment: Also, the response headers sent might be context-dependent.